# Distinct characters are independent.

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, field-theory

I am studying Galois theory.I am following the lecture series of K.Hanumanthu on *Introduction to Galois Theory*.He has started the topic with the definition of group characters.

> **Defn.** Let $G$ be a group and $F$ be a field,then a character of a group $G$ in a field $F$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $F^\times=F-\{0\}$.

Now he has defined characters $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n$ to be independent if
$a_1\sigma_1+...+a_n\sigma_n\equiv0$ for some $a_i\in F$$\implies a_1=...=a_n=0$.

Then he has stated a theorem:

> Distinct characters are independent.

I have understood upto this point.Now the instructor claims that:

> If $K,L$ are two fields and $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n:K\to L$ are distinct field homomorphisms such that $a_1\sigma_1(\alpha)+...+a_n\sigma_n(\alpha)=0$ for all $\alpha\in K$ then $a_1=a_2=...=a_n=0$.

I cannot understand how it follows from the independence theorem of characters because there the codomain was was $F^\times$ but here it is $L$.

Comment: here is a version of the argument: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CKK

Comment: @peterag It is ok,I have got the proof.But how does the corollary follow from there?

Comment: Please do not keep up updating your post/question in this manner! Your first version was quite different (reference request for exercises) which changed to a request about the proof. But, to address the "I cannot understand" (current version!),  the $\sigma_i: K\to L$  are field homomorphisms. So restricting to $K^*$, they are in particular group homomorphisms to $L^*$ (they carry multiplication to multiplication). [To apply the theorem, take, in the definition, $G=K^*$, and $L=F$.].

Comment: @peterag But how can you guarantee that $0\notin \sigma_i(K^*)$?

Comment: Oh sorry,we can guarantee as field homomorphisms are injective